# how do I add contents of the hash to a file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash which is printed in perl like this

```
SYSTEM:  Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04ZZZ:  Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04
```

where `SYSTEM:` , `ZZZ:` are keys and   `Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04`,   `Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04` are values (joined strings using join)

I want these to be appended to a existing file as key, value pairs (similar to config parser in python). I want appended file text be like this:

```
[section_]
ZZZ = [Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04]
SYSTEM = [Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04]
```

I'm new to Perl and I'm trying to implement it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you come across [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper)?

Comment: See also [Reading configuration INI files in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/reading-configuration-files-in-perl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Tiny;
my %hash = (
    SYSTEM => q[Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04],
    ZZZ => q[Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04]
);
my $Config = Config::Tiny->new();
$Config->{section_} = \%hash;
$Config->write('test.conf', 'utf8');
```

**Output**:

```
[section_]
SYSTEM=Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04
ZZZ=Sla:1MD7; Window: Any=00-04
```